# JQuery Mobile Grid inside Panel

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, panel

I've got a strange problem with a panel and a grid which i wanted to place inside this panel (my panel is almost using the whole space of the screen).

```
    <div id="panel" data-position="right" data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="false" > 
        <a href="#" id="closepanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"></a>
        <div class="ui-pannel-inner">

        <div data-role="panel-content" >

             <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        .. some html
             </div>

             <div class="ui-grid-c">    

                      <div class="ui-block-a" >
                           <a data-role="button"  data-corners="false" id="commit">commit</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <a data-role="button"  data-corners="false" id="commitAll">commit all</a>
                      </div>  

                      <div class="ui-block-c" >
                         <a data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="toggleInterval">toggle</a>
                      </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
```

When i use the upper markup the buttons are not displayed in the defined blocks. The first Button is ok, the seconds spans the whole area of block b and block c, the third button is in the next line ... i changed the way the buttons are displayed by using

....

Can anybody give me a hint why this is happening, though? Could be that i user panels for more often and i don't want to run into other problems with input fields or so ...

thanks a lot ...

andy

Comment: For a 3 column grid, use: class="ui-grid-b"

Comment: Maybe you can markup and update this fiddle to recreate your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6ezUL/

Comment: thank for your effort, seems to work and maybe i've got a problem with my surrounding markup. thanks a lot!!! best andy